# Use script library from another database

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

Is it possible to call script libraries from another database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly.  About the only thing you can do is have one database inherit from the other, and set only the lotusscript libraries to be inherited.  Then you could make changes on the parent, and have them carry over to the child (or children) databases.

You can, however, run agents on another database.  Agents in turn can make calls to script libraries in their own databases.  Depending on your goals, you may be able to get what you need from that.

Comment: I am trying to run an agent from LotusScript but nothing happens. This is my code: Dim agent As NotesAgent
  Set agent = destdb.Getagent("TestExternalUse")  
  If Not(Agent Is Nothing) Then
   Call Agent.Run   
  Else
   MsgBox "Agent not found..."
  End If

Comment: That code looks fine. Assuming it can find the agent, it will attempt to run it. What error are you seeing? Bear in mind that some agents won't run properly when triggered like this because the context isn't right (e.g. agents with front-end interactions such as the NotesUI* classes, or those designed to run on selected documents)

Comment: I have a view that contains a shared action written with Formula code. In that shared action an LotusScript agent is called. And from that LotusScript agent I want to start another agent in another database(destdb). The agent's name is "TestExternalUse". It is triggered on event, its target is None and it is shared.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, it seems that you are calling an agent within an agent. Not really the best way to go about it.

You may get the result you want if you merely call the "TextExternalUse" agent directly from the button. This means creating a regular action button rather than a shared action and calling the agent directly.

**UPDATE:**
I think I know what your problem is. If you're using formula to call the agent in the other database, it won't work, because formula can only call agents in the current database. So if you're using "ToolsRunMacro" it has no parameter for specifying a different database.

Try calling the agent with LotusScript. Here is an example.

I created 2 databases one with an agent called "clickme", which simply displays a "notesUIWorkspace.prompt", and another database with a view that has an action button with the following code that calls the agent from db1

```
  Sub Click(Source As Button)
     Dim agnt As notesAgent
     Dim db2 As notesDatabase

     Set db2 = New notesDatabase("","test2.nsf")
     Set agnt = db2.GetAgent("clickme")
     Call agnt.Run

    End Sub
```

Can you test something like the above ?

Comment: I've tried calling the agent from a shared action and from a button, but the agent does not run. It should display a message box. Maybe there is a security issue.

Comment: Are you getting an error message ? For it to merely do nothing is unusual. As long as (you) the user has access to the other database. It should work. I have ammended my answer above with a quick bit of code.

Comment: Let's consider this code: Dim agent As NotesAgent Set agent = destdb.Getagent("TestExternalUse") If Not(Agent Is Nothing) Then Call Agent.Run Else MsgBox "Agent not found..." End If

Comment: If I put a MessageBox statement before "Call Agent.Run" it will open a dialog box, but the action that is associated with the agent won't happen.